# SOLR schema to handle multiple connected multi-valued fields

Tags: solr

Suppose you have documents like these:

```
doc1:
 id:1
 text: ...
 references: Journal1, 2013, pag 123
 references: Journal2, 2014, pag 345

doc2
 id:2
 text:...
 references: Journal2, 2013, pag 678
 references: Journal1, 2014, pag 901
```

How can I structure my schema to search documents by reference?
My first hypothesis is something like this:

```
<doc>
 <field name="id">1</field>
 <field name="text">...</field>
 <field name="ref_journal">Journal1</field>
 <field name="ref_journal">Journal2</field>
 <field name="ref_year">2013</field>
 <field name="ref_year">2014</field>
 <field name="ref_page">123</field>
 <field name="ref_page">456</field>
</doc>
<doc>
 <field name="id">2</field>
 <field name="text">...</field>
 <field name="ref_journal">Journal2</field>
 <field name="ref_journal">Journal1</field>
 <field name="ref_year">2013</field>
 <field name="ref_year">2014</field>
 <field name="ref_page">678</field>
 <field name="ref_page">901</field>
</doc>
```

But in this way I can't enforce that first `ref_journal` field is connected to first `ref_year` field, so searching for `ref_journal:Journal1 AND ref_year:2013` will wrongly match both documents.
Is there a way to have multiple "connected" multi-valued fields?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to search only for exact values a tricky solution is to join multiple attributes in a single multivalued field with an appropriate tokenizer.

Define a "ref" type like this:

```
<fieldType name="ref" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\s*;\s*"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Create a multivalued field to store references:

```
<field name="ref" type="ref" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

Format data like this:

```
<doc>
 <field name="id">1</field>
 <field name="text">...</field>
 <field name="ref">journal:Journal1; year:2013 ; page:123</field>
 <field name="ref">journal:Journal2; year:2014 ; page:456</field>
</doc>
<doc>
 <field name="id">2</field>
 <field name="text">...</field>
 <field name="ref">journal:Journal2; year:2013; page:678;</field>
 <field name="ref">journal:Journal1; year:2014; page:901;</field>
</doc>
```

Search using proximity matching:

```
ref:"year:2014; journal:Journal2"~100
```

Note that:

- you cant't use semicolon in data: if you need it you've to find another appropriate separator.
- `positionIncrementGap` must be bigger than the number of possible attributes in ref to avoid matches across different fields.
- you can't use range queries

This is not a general solution but in most situations it can be adequate and probably easier to implement.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at [BlockJoin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers), that offers some support for that. Be warned it is not fully comparable to a sql db though, has some limitations, but it does support some use cases. If you really need this feature, check it out, even if it makes other things harder, might save you.

Comment: @cpburnz why did you delete my changes? Did them violate any rule?

Comment: @Zac Instead of adding significant content to someone else's post, you should post an answer of your own.

Answer (score 1):

Few days back I also got similar type of problem. So, I can suggest you a little different solution.

Let's take the help of data you provided. I would store the 2 documents as 4 different Solr documents. It's always better for Solr, if you simplify your document structure, rather than executing heavy join queries.

```
<doc>
 <field name="id">1</field>
 <field name="text">...</field>
 <field name="somefield">doc1</field>
 <field name="ref_journal">Journal1</field>
 <field name="ref_year">2013</field>
 <field name="ref_page">123</field>
</doc>
<doc>
 <field name="id">2</field>
 <field name="text">...</field>
 <field name="somefield">doc1</field>
 <field name="ref_journal">Journal2</field>
 <field name="ref_year">2014</field>
 <field name="ref_page">456</field>
</doc>
<doc>
 <field name="id">3</field>
 <field name="text">...</field>
 <field name="somefield">doc2</field>
 <field name="ref_journal">Journal2</field>
 <field name="ref_year">2013</field>
 <field name="ref_page">678</field>
</doc><doc>
 <field name="id">4</field>
 <field name="text">...</field>
 <field name="somefield">doc2</field>
 <field name="ref_journal">Journal1</field>
 <field name="ref_year">2014</field>
 <field name="ref_page">901</field>
</doc>
```

Now, if you query `ref_journal:Journal1 AND ref_year:2013` matches a single Solr document only. I have also added a field called "**somefield**" which says that first 2 Solr document belong to a single document and the other 2 document belong to a different document. This way you kept all the information related to your document. And also established a connection between the documents properly.

One more thing. Please don't worry about data redundancy and query performance. Because a simple query will always give you a better performance than a join query. Solr is not that much good in joins.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes, but if I search `text:some text` it will find multiplied documents in the result. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. Because that's also not unique filter you are providing. The data in the `text` field are same for the first 2 solr documents. So, you should get multiple documents. But that's not a problem. Providing more filters can resolve the issue.